# Multi-Select ListBox contents to Range

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, userform

Using VBA i have created a Userform with various Textboxes, Comboboxes & Listboxes.  I currently set it so that once you hit the Submit button (`Commandbutton1`), the various boxes contents fill a selected cell on my sheet.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D4") = TextBox1.Text
    Sheet2.Cells(5, 4) = ComboBox2.Text
    Sheet2.Cells(6, 4) = ComboBox1.Text
    Sheet2.Cells(7, 4) = TextBox2.Text
    Sheet2.Cells(8, 4) = TextBox4.Text

    UserForm1.Hide

End Sub
```

I also want the contents of my multiselect Listbox to do the same for cells (9, 4) - (15, 4) for example.  How can i do this? The options on this multi select list box range from Insight, Barracuda, Siena, Visio, Project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate the selected items of the `ListBox` and add them to an array. When you have collected all the selected items, transfer to the `Range`. For example:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    ' your code
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C8") = TextBox1.Text
    Sheets("sheet2").Range("C12") = ComboBox2.Text
    Sheets("sheet2").Range("F12") = ComboBox1.Text
    Sheets("sheet2").Range("F8") = TextBox2.Text
    Sheets("sheet2").Range("F10") = TextBox4.Text
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C30") = TextBox7.Text
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F29:F36") = TextBox8.Text

    ' my code to update the sheet with the listbox selections
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lng1 As Long
    Dim lng2 As Long
    Dim str() As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set rng = ws.Range("F22") ' (9, 4) - (15, 4)

    lng2 = 0 ' count of selected items
    For lng1 = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListBox1.Selected(lng1) Then
            lng2 = lng2 + 1 ' increment counter
            ReDim Preserve str(1 To lng2) ' resize array...
            str(lng2) = Me.ListBox1.List(lng1) ' and add selected item
        End If
    Next lng1

    ' transfer to range
    rng.Resize(lng2, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(str)

    ' close form
    'Unload Me
    UserForm1.Hide

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks,  I have tried to amend the code to what i need and get a Runtime 70 error, permission denied. @Robin Mackenzie

Comment: Which line throws the error ? Do you have protected worksheet, or protected cells on `Sheet2`?

Comment: The sheet & cells are not protected as of yet, the only relationship the form already has with the cells are row sources

Comment: Move 'UserForm1.Hide` to the end of the code I suggested and also maybe comment out `Unload Me` (because you are going to put `UserForm1.Hide` there instead)

Comment: I had removed that but it is still getting an error, even if remove the (.Add Item "DataStore").  It then errors at the next available line

Comment: How did you populate the listbox in your original code ?

Comment: from a row source to a hidden sheet under the listbox1 properties in vba editor

Comment: So it's not necessary to use that bit of my suggested code in  `UserForm_Initializie` - you can just get rid of that in your form and just use the bit of code in the click event to get the selected content of the ListBox. I'll update my answer to reflect our exchange.

Comment: This is working currently but for only one item selected in the list, how do i make it for multiple selected?